# Laravel Unit testing Routes

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, server, routes

My test method has:

```
 $this->visitRoute('route.name')->see('something');
```

Response:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\MyTest::testRoute
A request to [http://localhost/route.name] failed. Received status code [500].
Caused by
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 no such table 'tableThatExists'
```

BUT when I test:

```
$this->visit('/')
```

As provided in Laravel documentation, it works, what is wrong??

And also if I just want to test responses without "see" condition how do I do it?

If anybody knows simple basic laravel unit tests it could help as well

Comment: Are you using a `:memory:` database?

Comment: yes, I saw it in a tutorial but i don't completely understand why I do it

Comment: Can you show the route definition?

Comment: Route::resource('routename', 'DashRouteName');

Comment: Please, add the route definition to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\DatabaseMigrations;
```

in file and

```
use DatabaseMigrations;
```

in class

Answer (score 0):

This error is because the app test is not finding the database.

Try with:
Into `phpunit.xml` inside `php`tag you need to set a testing database like this

```
<php>
    <env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
    <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
    <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
    <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite"/>
    <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
</php>
```